# How can I remote run an SSIS package using DTEXEC?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dtexec

I'm very new to using dtexec and to deploying SSIS packages (mostly just run them in VS).  I would like to remote run a package that I have deployed to a server using DTEXEC...

The package name is SQL2012 Update Run.  When I open up SSMS, the package is found under

Integration Services Catalogs -> SSISDB -> ServerUpdate -> Projects -> UpdateRun -> Packages -> SQL2012 Update Run

The server name is 1555\C1592.

I have tried all sorts of variations on using the /sql command, the /ser command, /dts, /file, I just can't seem to get it to run.

How would I use the dtexec utility to run the package at the specified location using integrated security?

Edit: Oh and there are 4 parameters, 3 are strings and one is an int16, how would I pass these in?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how write dtexec with the dtsx file location and variable input.

example:

```
dtexec /F "C:\Temp\Test.dtsx" /SET \Package.Variables[User::Guess_A_Number].Properties[Value];3
```

Shell (Edit):

```
dtexec /F "<your_directory/<your_file>.dtsx" /SET \Package.Variables[<Your Variable>].Properties[Your Value];<Your Value>
```

Explanation:
/F is the location of your dtsx (SSIS) package
/SET to set your variables.

More info on dtexec:
[TechNet Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, the Microsoft API for /F states that this is not applicable to my scenario (as the package is deployed to an Integration Services server).  I did read the technet documentation, which is always a bit too vague for my liking... Would you be able to provide an example of how I would reference a string parameter at the package level?  Would it be /SET Package.Variables[myString];"StringValue" or /SET Package.Variables["myString"];"StringValue"?  The MSDN for dtexec would seem to suggest that /Par is the appropriate flag for setting parameters.

Comment: /SET \Package.Variables[User::Example_Variable].Properties[Value];"Hi"  Also, I believe to access a package on an IS Server is /ISSERVER "<location of package>".

Comment: Found a blog that explains how to use dtexec packages on an IS Server. Have not tried this myself since our packages are not deployed to an IS Server.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/24/using-dtexec-with-packages-on-the-is-server.aspx  Maybe someone will chime in on this to confirm.